# Ignore the command Line in Text File

Tags: c, cvi

how to compare two text file by ignoring the command "  //  Q_L1_M1F0" on second text file.

1.Text File

```
REG= 0x3e23, 0x0110
REG= 0x5d2w, 0x69E9
REG= 0x3e23, 0x7051
REG= 0x3s06, 0xB190
REG= 0x3e23, 0x5694
REG= 0x3e2f, 0x0130
```

2. text file ,

```
REG= 0x3e23, 0x0110     //  Q_L1_M1F0
REG= 0x5d2w, 0x69E9     //  Q_L1_M0F3
REG= 0x3e23, 0x7051     //  Q_L1_M4F0
REG= 0x3s06, 0xB190     //  Q_L1_M0F6
REG= 0x3e23, 0x5694     //  Q_L1_M7F0
REG= 0x3e2f, 0x0130     //  Q_L1_M2F6
```

Comment: So your actual question is "How can I strip C end line comments from a string"?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: yes

Comment: The I'd [edit] the the question accordingly. The less irrelevant information is in the, the more likely people will answer.

Comment: That's basic C string manipulation. Find the index of the last occurrence of `//`in the string. Put a NUL in the string at that index. Then strip the remaining spaces from the end of the string.

Comment: @user3121023 we don't know if the `//` comment is always in the same position.

Comment: the command and the space remains the same for all the lines. once i try to remove the command line i will use strcmp to compare the text. Could you say me which function to remove "    //  Q_L1_M2F4" ?

Comment: With shell: `diff -u <(sed -e 's:[ \t]*\(//.*\)*$::' file1) <(sed -e 's:[ \t]*\(//.*\)*$::' file2)`